# Pricing Secured Barrier Call

Tags: option-pricing, brownian-motion, binary-options, barrier, continuous-time

A European barrier call with barrier $B = 50$, expiration $T = 31$, and strike $K = 33$ costs $12$. The investor is interested in a product that, unlike this barrier call, offers some protection for the case that the stock goes above the barrier 50. The investor wants to buy an investment product called *Secured Barrier Call* whose payoff structure is

$$\text{Payoff}=
\begin{cases}
S(31)-33\quad, & \text{if} \hspace{2mm} S(31)\ge33 \hspace{2mm} \text{and} \hspace{2mm} S(t) < 50\quad,\hspace{5mm} \forall \,t\le 31 \\ 
50\hspace{2.2cm}, & \text{if} \hspace{2mm} S(t)\ge50 \hspace{2mm}\text{for some}\,\,t\le31 \\ 
0\hspace{2.45cm}, & \text{o.w}
\end{cases}$$

An American digital call with strike $33$ and expiration $31$ costs $0.73$, and the American digital call with strike $50$ and expiration $31$ costs $0.70$.

> I need to compute the price of the *Secured Barrier Call*. After
>   computation, I got $46.94$.

That's what I've done: $C_0=12-2\times0.73+52\times0.70=46.94$. But I am not confident about what I've got.

Could you please confirm or help me with any hint if it's wrong? Thank you.

P.S.: I recently started working on quantitative finance, and it's a problem that I found in book for practicing.

Comment: How do you reach your result that $C_0=12−2\times 0.73+52\times 0.70=46.94$? What is the reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of this exercise is to replicate the payoff of the Secured Barrier Call by a linear combination of the known products: European up-out call (cost 12), digital strike 33 (cost 0.73) and digital strike 50 (cost 0.7).

Looks to me it is sufficient to buy:

1. 1x up-out call
2. 50 x digital strike 50

The payout at expiry of this linear combination would be:

1. $(S(31) - 33)^+$ if S(t) <50 for all t <= 31
2. 50 if S(t) touched 50 at any time
3. 0 otherwise